# Restrict Members to their own files

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I want to have members register, then be able to publish content to a channel. That works fine, however when a user accesses the file manager to upload an image they have access to all images uploaded to that channel entry.

How do I restrict each user access to only the images they upload?
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach:

1. Put the users in a member group that has the member preference "*[Can edit entries authored by others](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#can-edit-entries-authored-by-others)*" set to "*No*"
2. Use [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-images) or [Channel Files](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-files) to manage the file uploads. These add-ons have per-entry file management, so they will create separate directories per Channel entry.

This combination effectively makes it so that members (at least in the group of interest) are only able to access files they have uploaded themselves.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that works great. I was looking at Channel Images but did not know it would do per-user file management. You recommendation saved my a*s.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped! It's not mandatory, but if I've answered your question you have the option to mark this answer as "accepted." See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) You currently have [two other questions](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/4992/user2254532?tab=questions) that have correct answers worth reviewing as well.

Comment: Channel Images is a great tool, however I wanted to use it with EE's grid, or Pixel & Tonic Matrix, but it was not compatible with either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ExpressionEngine will allow such behaviour out of the box although the exp_files table 'does' include a 'uploaded_by_member_id' column so it's possible that you could leverage that through a custom file select field type to limit what the user can pick from.